# How do I fix "tensorflow:Gradients do not exist for variables" errors in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

I'm building a Variational Auto-Encoder (VAE) model with Tensorflow 2.1.15 and Tensorflow-Probability 0.13.
My problem is that I can't avoid getting the **"Gradients does not exist for variables"**.

Here is the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
tfd = tfp.distributions
tfb = tfp.bijectors
tfpl = tfp.layers

import numpy as np

from tensorflow.keras import Sequential, Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import (Dense, Flatten, Reshape, Concatenate, Conv2D, 
                                     UpSampling2D, BatchNormalization)

print( "tf.version", tf.__version__, "tfp.version", tfp.__version__ )

prior_distribution = tfd.MultivariateNormalDiag( loc = np.zeros( ( 2, ) ), scale_diag = np.ones( ( 2, ) ) )

kl_regularizer = tfpl.KLDivergenceRegularizer(
    distribution_b = prior_distribution,
    use_exact_kl = False,
    test_points_fn = lambda t : t.sample( 3 ),
    test_points_reduce_axis = None,
    weight = 1.0
    )

def reconstruction_loss(batch_of_images, decoding_dist):
    return - tf.reduce_mean( decoding_dist.log_prob( batch_of_images ) )

image_array = np.random.uniform( 0, 1, ( 100, 36, 36, 3 ) ).astype( np.float64 ) / 255.0
train_dataset = image_array[ 0 : 80 ]
test_dataset = image_array[ 80 : 100 ]

encoder = tf.keras.Sequential( [
    Conv2D( 3, 3, padding = "same", input_shape = ( 36, 36, 3 ) ),
    Flatten( input_shape = ( 36, 36, 3 ) ),
    Dense( tfpl.MultivariateNormalTriL.params_size( 2 ), name = "encoder_dense" ),
    tfpl.MultivariateNormalTriL( 2, activity_regularizer = kl_regularizer, dtype = tf.float64, name = "encoder_outdist" )
])

decoder = tf.keras.Sequential( [
    Dense( 36 * 36 * 3, input_shape = ( 2, ), name = "decoder_dense" ),
    Reshape( ( 36, 36, 3 ), name = "decoder_reshape" ),
    Conv2D( 3, 3, padding = "same", name = "decoder_conv2d" ),
    Flatten( name = "decoder_flatten" ),
    tfpl.IndependentBernoulli( event_shape = ( 36, 36, 3 ), convert_to_tensor_fn = tfd.Bernoulli.logits )
])

vae = tf.keras.Model( inputs=encoder.inputs, outputs=decoder( encoder.outputs ) )
vae.compile( optimizer = "adam", loss = reconstruction_loss )

print( "vae.summary()", vae.summary() )

vae.fit( train_dataset, epochs = 5, batch_size = 20 )
```

and here is the result of executing this on Google Colab:

```
tf.version 2.5.0 tfp.version 0.13.0
Model: "model_37"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_38_input (InputLayer) [(None, 36, 36, 3)]       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_38 (Conv2D)           (None, 36, 36, 3)         84        
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_38 (Flatten)         (None, 3888)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
encoder_dense (Dense)        (None, 5)                 19445     
_________________________________________________________________
encoder_outdist (Multivariat multiple                  0         
_________________________________________________________________
sequential_77 (Sequential)   multiple                  11748     
=================================================================
Total params: 31,277
Trainable params: 31,277
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
vae.summary() None
Epoch 1/5
WARNING:tensorflow:Gradients do not exist for variables ['decoder_dense/kernel:0', 'decoder_dense/bias:0', 'decoder_conv2d/kernel:0', 'decoder_conv2d/bias:0'] when minimizing the loss.
WARNING:tensorflow:Gradients do not exist for variables ['decoder_dense/kernel:0', 'decoder_dense/bias:0', 'decoder_conv2d/kernel:0', 'decoder_conv2d/bias:0'] when minimizing the loss.
4/4 [==============================] - 1s 12ms/step - loss: 0.0196
Epoch 2/5
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 10ms/step - loss: 0.0092
Epoch 3/5
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 12ms/step - loss: 0.0023
Epoch 4/5
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 10ms/step - loss: 0.0029
Epoch 5/5
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 10ms/step - loss: 0.0029
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7fd95cb15e50>
```

I believe that when this occurs it also messes up the optimization.  I'm at a loss as to how to fix the problem.  Can you please help?

Comment: It means that your models don't have a Y to compute loss on for the decoder stack and hence can't compute gradients. You have to check your train_dataset and give Y to the model.

Comment: @abhishek-prajapat, I see what you are saying, but in all the examples of VAE's that I've seen, there is no "y" parameter; for example, see https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/examples/Probabilistic_Layers_VAE

Comment: `y` is the `train_data` actually. It should be `vae.fit( train_dataset, train_dataset, epochs = 5, batch_size = 20 )`

Comment: Yes, for an AutoEncoder, you'd compare the input image and the reconstructed output image.   However, for the Variational case, the output is a distribution (Ind. Bernoulli) and the loss is (minus) how probable the input image is according to that distribution.

Comment: @MarkLavin In those examples, `y` is also included in the dataset. Actually the `train_data` returns a tuple of (x,y) instead of just x. In this way you don't need to pass argument `y` separately.

Comment: @Frightera, Kaveh, abhishek-prajapat, you are all quite right.   Changing the definition of the dataset to contain two copies of the inputs fixes the "gradients do not exist" error and now the VAE gives reasonable-looking results.   Thanks!

Comment: @MarkLavin, I made the same mistake in the fit() method as you, and like you I was results (infact, they were pretty good). Now fixing this, made the errors look too bad. I am confused as why did it run before. Any idea?

Comment: @MarkLavin! Could you try again after providing a target dataset in vae.fit () operation ?